# How to find out the position of the icon?

Tags: html, css

I have a sprite of icons:

```
http://i.piccy.info/i9/3d2e4aea3daed4a0057c88c6e7c1b6a0/1566832397/25899/1334677/Screenshot_12.png
```

I need to insert the last icon in the menu, next to the text.

CSS with code looks like that:

```
.game-tab .left-header .game-icon.double,
.history-top .left-header .game-icon.double {
background-position: -48px -38px
}
.menu .navigation .game-selector-list .game-selector.active .game-info .game-icon.double {
background-position: -5px -137px
}
.menu .navigation .game-selector-list .game-selector .game-info .game-icon.double {
background-position: -5px -93px
}
```

As I understand it, to insert the last icon, I need to calculate the pixels and fit in the css? How can i do this? Or how to display this icon correctly?

Comment: Technically if you have generated the sprite of icons, you will know the size of each icon and can deduce the position by mathematics. If not, you can manually adjust the number until it fits.

Comment: i use ready sprites, i don't generated

Comment: Open the sprite in an image editor. Then you can measure actual pixels from top and side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the first one for you

```
.first{
  background-image: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/3d2e4aea3daed4a0057c88c6e7c1b6a0/1566832397/25899/1334677/Screenshot_12.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -85px -18px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
```

from this, subtract about 44 from -18 for each subsiquent image.